# Connect React Application with windows service hosting SignalR

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asp.net, asp.net-core, signalr

I got error while connecting my react application with windows service developed in asp.net (and not .net core) which hosts SignalR as well.

It gives Error: Failed to start the connection: Error: Detected a connection attempt to an ASP.NET SignalR Server. This client only supports connecting to an ASP.NET Core SignalR Server. Give me some solution for connecting my react app with asp.net core any link or website that will be usefull.
The Startup.cs file

```
using Owin;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Microsoft.Owin.Cors;
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR;

[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(WindowsServiceTutorial.Startup))]
namespace WindowsServiceTutorial
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
            app.MapSignalR("/MyHub", new HubConfiguration
            {
                // You can enable JSONP by uncommenting line below.
                // JSONP requests are insecure but some older browsers (and some
                // versions of IE) require JSONP to work cross domain
                EnableJSONP = false,

                // Turns on sending detailed information to clients when errors occur, disable for production
                EnableDetailedErrors = true,
                EnableJavaScriptProxies = true
            });
        }
    }
}
```

The SignalR.cs file

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace WindowsServiceTutorial
{
    internal class SignalR
    {
        public class MyHub : Hub
        {
            public void SendMessage(string message)
            {
                Clients.All.sendMessage(message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The Service.cs file

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.ServiceProcess;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Timers;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Threading;
using Owin;
using Microsoft.Owin.Cors;
using Microsoft.Owin.Host;
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Hubs;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client;
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Infrastructure;
using Microsoft.Owin.Hosting;

//using Microsoft.Owin.Cors;
//using Microsoft.Owin.Hosting;
//using Owin;

namespace WindowsServiceTutorial
{
    public partial class Service1 : ServiceBase
    {
        private IDisposable signalR;

        public Service1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        
        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                string url = "http://localhost:5000";
                signalR = WebApp.Start(url);
                WriteToFile("Project start Finally");
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                WriteToFile(e.StackTrace);
                WriteToFile(e.Message);
                WriteToFile(e.InnerException?.StackTrace);
                WriteToFile(e.InnerException?.Message);
            }

            WriteToFile("Serive is started at " + DateTime.Now);
            //timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnElapsedTime);
            //timer.Interval = 5000;
            //timer.Enabled = true;
            Task.Delay(20000);
            WriteToFile("Delay done " + DateTime.Now);      
        }

        
protected override void OnStop()
        {
            WriteToFile("service is stopped at" + DateTime.Now);
        }
        private void OnElapsedTime(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            WriteToFile("Service is recall at" + DateTime.Now);
        }
        public void WriteToFile(string Message)
        {
            string path = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "\\Logs";
            if (!Directory.Exists(path))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
            }
            string filepath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "\\Logs\\ServiceLog_" + DateTime.Now.Date.ToShortDateString().Replace('/', '_') + ".txt";
            if (!File.Exists(filepath))
            {
                using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(filepath))
                {
                    sw.WriteLine(Message);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(filepath))
                {
                    sw.WriteLine(Message);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now in React side code i have this

```
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import * as signalR from '@microsoft/signalr';
import { useState } from 'react';

function App() {

  const [hubConnection, setHubConnection] = useState(null);

  function Connect() {
    const connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
      .withUrl("http://localhost:5000/Myhub")
      .build();

    connection.start()
      .then(() => { setHubConnection(connection); console.log("SignalR Connected!") })
      .catch(err => { alert(err); console.error("Error connecting to SignalR:", err) });

    connection.on("chartStation1", (data) => {
      console.log(data);
    });

    return () => {
      connection.stop();
    };
  }

  function sendMessage() {
    hubConnection.invoke('NewMessage', 'client', 'You have a notification from the front end !')
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="container">
        <button onClick={Connect}>Connect</button>   
        <button onClick={sendMessage}>send meassge</button>   
      </div>
    </div>
  );

}

export default App;
```

Error: Failed to start the connection: Error: Detected a connection attempt to an ASP.NET SignalR Server. This client only supports connecting to an ASP.NET Core SignalR Server.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The error message you're getting that indicate the SignalR client you're using on the React side is intended for ASP.NET Core SignalR, but it seems you're trying to connect to an ASP.NET SignalR server which is the older version. The two versions are not compatible with each other.If possible you could try to upgrade your SignalR server to ASP.NET Core.

If it is not possible to upgrade, you could try using SignalR client that is compatible with ASP.NET SignalR.

Here is the  older SignalR client in your React app code you could try:

```
import $ from 'jquery';
import 'signalr'; 

function App() {
  // ...

  function Connect() {
    const connection = $.hubConnection("http://localhost:5000/");
    const hubProxy = connection.createHubProxy('MyHub');

    connection.start()
      .done(() => {
        console.log('Now connected, connection ID=' + connection.id);
        setHubConnection(connection); 
      })
      .fail(err => {
        alert(err);
        console.error('Could not connect', err);
      });

    hubProxy.on('sendMessage', (message) => {
      console.log(message);
    });

    return () => {
      connection.stop();
    };
  }

  // ...
}
```

Reference document for upgrading to ASP.NET Core SignalR:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/introduction?view=aspnetcore-8.0